# Is this how you do a dynamic Spring Cloud Gateway?

Tags: java, spring-cloud

I wrote a dynamic Gateway (there were other collaborators, but the version below is 90% my code). What makes it dynamic is the fact that it builds routes in runtime from Swagger docs it fetches from other Eureka applications. So the basic flow is:

1. It looks around and finds other Eureka applications
2. It fetches docs from those apps, parses them
3. Builds routes from each of the exposed endpoints (unless they are *filtered out*, see `EndpointSieve`)

New services and endpoints can be added in runtime, this Gateway will notice it and update its routes accordingly

My Gateway understands `/auth` as a non-semantic prefix. This Gateway will ignore it: for instance, endpoint `GET /auth/example` will be mapped to route `GET /api/v1/example` (`/api/v1` is this Gateway's path prefix, can be configured through `application-dev.yml`)

My Gateway has a type called `ParamInitializer`. `ParamInitializer`s recognize certain parameter names and add such parameters to requests. At this point, I only have one implementation, `PrincipalParamInitializer` which adds a `principal` parameter with principal name as its value (which is, in turn, a `sub` value extracted from the JWT token). All your endpoint has to do is to declare a `principal` parameter (doesn't matter if it's required or not)

**Requirements:**

1. You need a Eureka server running. You may use [this one](https://www.editpad.org/?edit-id=DsDenTZAuHbf03fae6), nothing special
2. Your service(s) should expose its API through `/v3/api-docs` (it's the default, it's configurable). One way to achieve that is to include this dependency in the service's `pom`:

```xml
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springdoc</groupId>
            <artifactId>springdoc-openapi-ui</artifactId>
            <version>1.7.0</version>
        </dependency>
```

3. Your service(s) should be client(s) of the same Eureka server. Basically, you need to include a `spring-cloud-starter-netflix-eureka-client` dependency and, if you use my Eureka server, not override the default Eureka port

You may use my [simplistic service](https://www.editpad.org/?edit-id=41Og525UvRbf1105ad)

What do you think? You can [pull](https://github.com/NadChel/dynamic-gateway) (though the remote repository can change and not fully reflect the snippets bellow)

Please note that my main class (it's basic), properties and pom (those are less basic) didn't fit due to the character limit. They can be found [here](https://www.editpad.org/?edit-id=Vo2k5QKT5uba4e6c34)

## Service

```java
package com.example.dynamicgateway.service.applicationFinder;


import com.example.dynamicgateway.model.discoverableApplication.DiscoverableApplication;

import java.util.Set;

/**
 * Interface implemented by classes that can fetch applications registered with the same discovery service
 * as this application
 */
public interface ApplicationFinder {
    /**
     * Returns a {@code Set} of {@link DiscoverableApplication}s excluding this application
     */
    Set<? extends DiscoverableApplication> findOtherRegisteredApplications();
}
```

```java
package com.example.dynamicgateway.service.applicationFinder;

import com.example.dynamicgateway.model.discoverableApplication.EurekaDiscoverableApplication;
import com.netflix.discovery.CacheRefreshedEvent;
import com.netflix.discovery.EurekaClient;
import com.netflix.discovery.shared.Application;
import lombok.extern.slf4j.Slf4j;
import org.springframework.context.ApplicationEventPublisher;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Component;

import java.util.Set;
import java.util.stream.Collectors;

/**
 * {@link ApplicationFinder} that relies on Netflix Eureka as its discovery service
 */
@Slf4j
@Component
public class EurekaApplicationFinder implements ApplicationFinder {
    private final EurekaClient eurekaClient;

    public EurekaApplicationFinder(EurekaClient eurekaClient, ApplicationEventPublisher publisher) {
        this.eurekaClient = eurekaClient;
        this.eurekaClient.registerEventListener(event -> {
            if (event instanceof CacheRefreshedEvent) {
                publisher.publishEvent(event);
            }
        });
    }

    @Override
    public Set<EurekaDiscoverableApplication> findOtherRegisteredApplications() {
        return eurekaClient.getApplications()
                .getRegisteredApplications()
                .stream()
                .filter(app -> !isSelf(app))
                .map(EurekaDiscoverableApplication::from)
                .collect(Collectors.toSet());
    }

    private boolean isSelf(Application application) {
        String nameOfThisApplication = eurekaClient.getApplicationInfoManager()
                .getInfo()
                .getAppName();
        return application.getName().equals(nameOfThisApplication);
    }
}
```

```java
package com.example.dynamicgateway.service.endpointCollector;

import com.example.dynamicgateway.model.documentedEndpoint.DocumentedEndpoint;
import org.springframework.http.HttpMethod;

import java.util.Set;

/**
 * Local cache of all known {@link DocumentedEndpoint}s
 *
 * @param <T> type of {@link DocumentedEndpoint}s that are collected by this {@code EndpointCollector}
 */
public interface EndpointCollector<T extends DocumentedEndpoint<?>> {
    /**
     * Returns a {@code Set} of all {@link DocumentedEndpoint}s cached by this {@code EndpointCollector}
     */
    Set<T> getKnownEndpoints();

    boolean hasEndpoint(HttpMethod method, String path);
}
```

```java
package com.example.dynamicgateway.service.endpointCollector;

import com.example.dynamicgateway.client.ApplicationDocClient;
import com.example.dynamicgateway.events.DocumentedEndpointFoundEvent;
import com.example.dynamicgateway.model.discoverableApplication.DiscoverableApplication;
import com.example.dynamicgateway.model.documentedApplication.SwaggerApplication;
import com.example.dynamicgateway.model.documentedEndpoint.SwaggerEndpoint;
import com.example.dynamicgateway.service.applicationFinder.ApplicationFinder;
import com.example.dynamicgateway.service.endpointSieve.EndpointSieve;
import com.netflix.discovery.CacheRefreshedEvent;
import io.swagger.v3.parser.core.models.SwaggerParseResult;
import lombok.extern.slf4j.Slf4j;
import org.springframework.boot.context.event.ApplicationReadyEvent;
import org.springframework.context.ApplicationEventPublisher;
import org.springframework.context.event.EventListener;
import org.springframework.http.HttpMethod;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Component;
import reactor.core.publisher.Mono;

import java.text.MessageFormat;
import java.util.HashSet;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Set;

/**
 * Local cache of {@link SwaggerEndpoint}s
 */
@Component
@Slf4j
public class SwaggerEndpointCollector implements EndpointCollector<SwaggerEndpoint> {
    public final Set<SwaggerEndpoint> documentedEndpoints = new HashSet<>();
    public final ApplicationFinder applicationFinder;
    private final ApplicationDocClient<SwaggerParseResult> applicationDocClient;
    private final ApplicationEventPublisher eventPublisher;
    private final List<EndpointSieve> endpointSieves;

    public SwaggerEndpointCollector(
            ApplicationFinder applicationFinder,
            ApplicationDocClient<SwaggerParseResult> applicationDocClient,
            ApplicationEventPublisher eventPublisher,
            List<EndpointSieve> endpointSieves) {
        this.applicationFinder = applicationFinder;
        this.applicationDocClient = applicationDocClient;
        this.eventPublisher = eventPublisher;
        this.endpointSieves = endpointSieves;
    }

    @Override
    public Set<SwaggerEndpoint> getCollectedEndpoints() {
        return documentedEndpoints;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean hasEndpoint(HttpMethod method, String path) {
        return documentedEndpoints.stream()
                .anyMatch(endpoint -> endpoint.getDetails().getMethod().equals(method) &&
                        endpoint.getDetails().getPath().equals(path));
    }

    @EventListener(ApplicationReadyEvent.class)
    public void onApplicationReadyEvent() {
        log.info("onApplicationReadyEvent() triggered");
        refreshEndpoints();
    }

    @EventListener(CacheRefreshedEvent.class)
    public void onCacheRefreshedEvent() {
        log.info("onCacheRefreshedEvent() triggered");
        refreshEndpoints();
    }

    private void refreshEndpoints() {
        log.info("Endpoint discovery started");
        Set<? extends DiscoverableApplication> applications = applicationFinder.findOtherRegisteredApplications();
        applications.forEach(this::subscribeToDocs);
    }

    private void subscribeToDocs(DiscoverableApplication application) {
        Mono<SwaggerParseResult> appDocMono = applicationDocClient.findApplicationDoc(application);
        appDocMono
                .map(applicationDoc -> new SwaggerApplication(application, applicationDoc))
                .flatMapIterable(SwaggerApplication::getEndpoints)
                .filter(this::passesThroughSieves)
                .subscribe(this::addEndpoint);
    }

    private boolean passesThroughSieves(SwaggerEndpoint endpoint) {
        return endpointSieves.stream()
                .allMatch(endpointSieve -> endpointSieve.isAllowed(endpoint));
    }

    private void addEndpoint(SwaggerEndpoint endpoint) {
        boolean isEndpointAdded = documentedEndpoints.add(endpoint);
        if (isEndpointAdded) {
            log.info(MessageFormat.format(
                    "New endpoint is collected: {0}",
                    endpoint
            ));
            eventPublisher.publishEvent(new DocumentedEndpointFoundEvent(endpoint, this));
        }
    }
}
```

```java
package com.example.dynamicgateway.service.endpointSieve;

import com.example.dynamicgateway.model.documentedEndpoint.DocumentedEndpoint;

public interface EndpointSieve {
    boolean isAllowed(DocumentedEndpoint<?> endpoint);
}
```

```java
package com.example.dynamicgateway.service.paramInitializer;

import org.springframework.cloud.gateway.route.Route;

public interface ParamInitializer {
    String getInitializedParam();

    void initialize(Route.AsyncBuilder routeInConstruction);
}
```

```java
package com.example.dynamicgateway.service.paramInitializer.impl;

import com.example.dynamicgateway.service.paramInitializer.ParamInitializer;
import org.springframework.cloud.gateway.filter.OrderedGatewayFilter;
import org.springframework.cloud.gateway.route.Route;
import org.springframework.http.server.reactive.ServerHttpRequest;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Component;
import org.springframework.web.server.ServerWebExchange;
import org.springframework.web.util.UriComponentsBuilder;

import java.net.URI;

@Component
public class PrincipalParamInitializer implements ParamInitializer {
    @Override
    public String getInitializedParam() {
        return "principal";
    }

    @Override
    public void initialize(Route.AsyncBuilder routeInConstruction) {
        routeInConstruction.filter(new OrderedGatewayFilter(
                (exchange, chain) -> exchange.getPrincipal()
                        .flatMap(principal -> {
                            URI newUri = UriComponentsBuilder
                                    .fromUri(exchange.getRequest().getURI())
                                    .queryParam(getInitializedParam(), principal.getName())
                                    .build(true)
                                    .toUri();

                            ServerHttpRequest newRequest = exchange
                                    .getRequest()
                                    .mutate()
                                    .uri(newUri)
                                    .build();

                            ServerWebExchange newExchange = exchange
                                    .mutate()
                                    .request(newRequest)
                                    .build();

                            return chain.filter(newExchange);
                        }), 0));
    }
}
```

```java
package com.example.dynamicgateway.service.paramInitializer;

import com.example.dynamicgateway.model.endpointParameter.EndpointParameter;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Component;

import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Map;
import java.util.Optional;

@Component
public class ParamInitializers {
    private final Map<String, ParamInitializer> paramToParamInitializerMap;

    public ParamInitializers(List<ParamInitializer> paramInitializers) {
        HashMap<String, ParamInitializer> paramToParamInitializerMap = new HashMap<>();
        for (ParamInitializer paramInitializer : paramInitializers) {
            paramToParamInitializerMap.put(paramInitializer.getInitializedParam(), paramInitializer);
        }
        this.paramToParamInitializerMap = paramToParamInitializerMap;
    }

    public Optional<ParamInitializer> findInitializerForParam(EndpointParameter param) {
        return Optional.ofNullable(paramToParamInitializerMap.get(param.getName()));
    }
}
```

```java
package com.example.dynamicgateway.service.routeLocator;

import com.example.dynamicgateway.events.DocumentedEndpointFoundEvent;
import com.example.dynamicgateway.model.documentedEndpoint.DocumentedEndpoint;
import com.example.dynamicgateway.service.routeProcessor.EndpointRouteProcessor;
import lombok.RequiredArgsConstructor;
import lombok.extern.slf4j.Slf4j;
import org.springframework.cloud.gateway.route.Route;
import org.springframework.cloud.gateway.route.RouteLocator;
import org.springframework.context.event.EventListener;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Component;
import reactor.core.publisher.Flux;

import java.text.MessageFormat;
import java.util.HashSet;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Set;

/**
 * {@link RouteLocator} that supplies {@link Route}s dynamically built from discovered {@link DocumentedEndpoint}s
 */
@Component
@Slf4j
@RequiredArgsConstructor
public class DynamicRouteLocator implements RouteLocator {
    private final Set<Route> routes = new HashSet<>();
    private final List<EndpointRouteProcessor> endpointRouteProcessors;

    @Override
    public Flux<Route> getRoutes() {
        log.info(MessageFormat.format(
                "getRoutes() is invoked. The method is about to return a Flux of {0} route(s)",
                routes.size()
        ));
        return Flux.fromIterable(routes);
    }

    @EventListener
    public void onDocumentedEndpointFoundEvent(DocumentedEndpointFoundEvent event) {
        DocumentedEndpoint<?> foundEndpoint = event.getFoundEndpoint();
        Route route = transformToRoute(foundEndpoint);
        boolean isNewRouteAdded = routes.add(route);

        if (isNewRouteAdded) {
            log.info(MessageFormat.format("""
                            New route is built:
                            -----------------------------------
                            {0}
                            -----------------------------------
                            Will be available at the next getRoutes() invocation""",
                    route
            ));
        }
    }

    private Route transformToRoute(DocumentedEndpoint<?> documentedEndpoint) {
        Route.AsyncBuilder routeBuilder = Route.async();
        for (EndpointRouteProcessor endpointRouteProcessor : endpointRouteProcessors) {
            routeBuilder = endpointRouteProcessor.process(routeBuilder, documentedEndpoint);
        }
        return routeBuilder.build();
    }
}
```

```java
package com.example.dynamicgateway.service.routeProcessor;

import org.springframework.cloud.gateway.route.Route;

/**
 * Interface to mark classes whose instances can mutate a {@link Route} builder based on the provided model
 *
 * @param <T> type of model this {@code RouteProcessor} can use to alter {@code Route} builders
 */
@FunctionalInterface
public interface RouteProcessor<T> {
    Route.AsyncBuilder process(Route.AsyncBuilder routeInConstruction, T model);
}
```

```java
package com.example.dynamicgateway.service.routeProcessor;

import com.example.dynamicgateway.model.documentedEndpoint.DocumentedEndpoint;
import org.springframework.cloud.gateway.route.Route;

/**
 * {@link RouteProcessor} that sources mutation data from supplied {@link DocumentedEndpoint}s
 */
@FunctionalInterface
public interface EndpointRouteProcessor extends RouteProcessor<DocumentedEndpoint<?>> {
    Route.AsyncBuilder process(Route.AsyncBuilder routeInConstruction, DocumentedEndpoint<?> endpoint);
}
```

```java
package com.example.dynamicgateway.service.swaggerUiSupport;

import com.example.dynamicgateway.model.uiConfig.SwaggerUiConfig;
import io.swagger.v3.oas.models.OpenAPI;
import reactor.core.publisher.Mono;

/**
 * Interface for marking utilities that simplify Swagger UI integration
 */
public interface SwaggerUiSupport {
    Mono<SwaggerUiConfig> getSwaggerUiConfig();

    Mono<OpenAPI> getSwaggerAppDoc(String appName);
}
```

```java
package com.example.dynamicgateway.service.swaggerUiSupport;

import com.example.dynamicgateway.model.documentedApplication.DocumentedApplication;
import com.example.dynamicgateway.model.documentedApplication.SwaggerApplication;
import com.example.dynamicgateway.model.documentedEndpoint.DocumentedEndpoint;
import com.example.dynamicgateway.model.documentedEndpoint.SwaggerEndpoint;
import com.example.dynamicgateway.model.gatewayMeta.GatewayMeta;
import com.example.dynamicgateway.model.uiConfig.SwaggerUiConfig;
import com.example.dynamicgateway.service.endpointCollector.EndpointCollector;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper;
import io.swagger.v3.oas.models.OpenAPI;
import io.swagger.v3.oas.models.PathItem;
import io.swagger.v3.oas.models.Paths;
import io.swagger.v3.parser.core.models.SwaggerParseResult;
import lombok.RequiredArgsConstructor;
import lombok.SneakyThrows;
import lombok.extern.slf4j.Slf4j;
import org.springframework.http.HttpMethod;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Component;
import reactor.core.publisher.Mono;

import java.text.MessageFormat;
import java.util.Map;
import java.util.NoSuchElementException;
import java.util.Set;
import java.util.stream.Collectors;

@Component
@Slf4j
@RequiredArgsConstructor
public class BasicSwaggerUiSupport implements SwaggerUiSupport {
    private final EndpointCollector<SwaggerEndpoint> endpointCollector;
    private final GatewayMeta gatewayMeta;
    private final ObjectMapper objectMapper;

    @Override
    public Mono<SwaggerUiConfig> getSwaggerUiConfig() {
        Set<SwaggerApplication> swaggerApps = endpointCollector.getCollectedEndpoints().stream()
                .map(DocumentedEndpoint::getDeclaringApp)
                .collect(Collectors.toSet());
        return Mono.just(SwaggerUiConfig.from(swaggerApps));
    }

    @Override
    @SneakyThrows
    public Mono<OpenAPI> getSwaggerAppDoc(String appName) {
        return Mono.just(
                endpointCollector.getCollectedEndpoints().stream()
                        .map(DocumentedEndpoint::getDeclaringApp)
                        .filter(documentedApplication -> documentedApplication.getName().equals(appName))
                        .map(DocumentedApplication::getNativeDoc)
                        .map(SwaggerParseResult::getOpenAPI)
                        .map(this::deepCopy)
                        .peek(this::removeIgnoredEndpoints)
                        .peek(this::setGatewayPrefixes)
                        .peek(this::setGatewayServers)
                        .findFirst()
                        .orElseThrow(() -> new IllegalArgumentException(MessageFormat.format(
                                "No service with name {0} is known to this Gateway", appName
                        )))
        );
    }

    @SneakyThrows
    private OpenAPI deepCopy(OpenAPI openAPI) {
        String serializedOpenApi = objectMapper.writeValueAsString(openAPI);
        return objectMapper.readValue(serializedOpenApi, OpenAPI.class);
    }

    private void removeIgnoredEndpoints(OpenAPI openAPI) {
        Paths newPaths = openAPI.getPaths().entrySet().stream()
                .peek(pathPathItemEntry -> pathPathItemEntry.getValue()
                        .readOperationsMap()
                        .forEach((method, operation) -> {
                            HttpMethod springMethod = HttpMethod.valueOf(method.toString());
                            String path = pathPathItemEntry.getKey();
                            if (!endpointCollector.hasEndpoint(springMethod, path)) {
                                pathPathItemEntry.getValue().operation(method, null);
                            }
                        }))
                .filter(pathPathItemEntry -> !pathPathItemEntry.getValue().readOperationsMap().isEmpty())
                .collect(Collectors.toMap(Map.Entry::getKey, Map.Entry::getValue, (oldVal, newVal) -> newVal, Paths::new));
        openAPI.setPaths(newPaths);
    }

    private void setGatewayPrefixes(OpenAPI openAPI) {
        Paths newPaths = new Paths();
        for (Map.Entry<String, PathItem> pathItemEntry : openAPI.getPaths().entrySet()) {
            String servicePath = pathItemEntry.getKey();
            PathItem pathItem = pathItemEntry.getValue();

            String nonprefixedPath = endpointCollector.getCollectedEndpoints().stream()
                    .filter(documentedEndpoint -> documentedEndpoint.getDetails().getPath().equals(servicePath))
                    .map(documentedEndpoint -> documentedEndpoint.getDetails().getNonPrefixedPath())
                    .findFirst()
                    .orElseThrow(() -> new NoSuchElementException(MessageFormat.format(
                            "No endpoint found. Requested path: {0}", servicePath
                    )));

            String prefixedPath = gatewayMeta.v1Prefix() + nonprefixedPath;
            newPaths.put(prefixedPath, pathItem);
        }
        openAPI.setPaths(newPaths);
    }

    private void setGatewayServers(OpenAPI openAPI) {
        openAPI.setServers(gatewayMeta.servers());
    }
}
```

```java
package com.example.dynamicgateway.service.swaggerUiSupport;

import com.example.dynamicgateway.model.documentedApplication.SwaggerApplication;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.core.JsonGenerator;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.JsonSerializer;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.SerializerProvider;
import lombok.SneakyThrows;

import java.text.MessageFormat;

public class SwaggerUiConfigSerializer extends JsonSerializer<SwaggerApplication> {
    @Override
    @SneakyThrows
    public void serialize(SwaggerApplication swaggerApplication, JsonGenerator jsonGenerator, SerializerProvider serializerProvider) {
        jsonGenerator.writeStartObject();
        jsonGenerator.writeStringField("url", MessageFormat.format("/doc/{0}", swaggerApplication.getName()));
        jsonGenerator.writeStringField("name", swaggerApplication.getName());
        jsonGenerator.writeEndObject();
    }
}
```

## Model

```java
package com.example.dynamicgateway.model.discoverableApplication;

/**
 * Application whose instances can be located by means of a discovery service
 */
public interface DiscoverableApplication {
    String getName();

    String getDiscoveryServiceScheme();
}
```

```java
package com.example.dynamicgateway.model.discoverableApplication;

import com.netflix.discovery.shared.Application;
import lombok.RequiredArgsConstructor;

/**
 * {@link DiscoverableApplication} that wraps a Eureka-registered {@link Application}
 */
@RequiredArgsConstructor
public class EurekaDiscoverableApplication implements DiscoverableApplication {
    public static final String LB_SCHEME = "lb://";
    private final Application eurekaApplication;

    @Override
    public String getName() {
        return eurekaApplication.getName();
    }

    @Override
    public String getDiscoveryServiceScheme() {
        return LB_SCHEME;
    }

    public static EurekaDiscoverableApplication from(Application application) {
        return new EurekaDiscoverableApplication(application);
    }
}
```

```java
package com.example.dynamicgateway.model.documentedApplication;

import com.example.dynamicgateway.model.discoverableApplication.DiscoverableApplication;
import com.example.dynamicgateway.model.documentedEndpoint.DocumentedEndpoint;

import java.util.List;

/**
 * Application that exposes its API documentation, including available endpoints
 *
 * @param <T> type of document object of this {@code DocumentedApplication}
 */
public interface DocumentedApplication<T> {
    DiscoverableApplication getDiscoverableApp();

    String getDescription();

    List<? extends DocumentedEndpoint<?>> getEndpoints();

    T getNativeDoc();

    default String getName() {
        return getDiscoverableApp().getName();
    }
}
```

```java
package com.example.dynamicgateway.model.documentedApplication;

import com.example.dynamicgateway.model.discoverableApplication.DiscoverableApplication;
import com.example.dynamicgateway.model.documentedEndpoint.SwaggerEndpoint;
import com.example.dynamicgateway.model.endpointDetails.EndpointDetails;
import com.example.dynamicgateway.model.endpointDetails.SwaggerEndpointDetails;
import io.swagger.v3.oas.models.Operation;
import io.swagger.v3.oas.models.PathItem;
import io.swagger.v3.parser.core.models.SwaggerParseResult;
import lombok.Getter;

import java.text.MessageFormat;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Map;
import java.util.stream.Stream;

/**
 * {@link DocumentedApplication} that exposes its API by means of Swagger (Open API)
 */
public class SwaggerApplication implements DocumentedApplication<SwaggerParseResult> {
    public static final String V3_DOC_PATH = "/v3/api-docs";
    private final DiscoverableApplication application;
    @Getter
    private final String description;
    private final List<SwaggerEndpoint> endpoints;
    private final SwaggerParseResult doc;

    public SwaggerApplication(DiscoverableApplication application, SwaggerParseResult parseResult) {
        this.application = application;
        this.doc = parseResult;
        this.description = parseResult.getOpenAPI().getInfo().getDescription();
        this.endpoints = extractEndpoints(parseResult);
    }

    private List<SwaggerEndpoint> extractEndpoints(SwaggerParseResult parseResult) {
        return parseResult.getOpenAPI()
                .getPaths()
                .entrySet()
                .stream()
                .flatMap(this::getEndpointStream)
                .toList();
    }

    private Stream<SwaggerEndpoint> getEndpointStream(Map.Entry<String, PathItem> pathPathItemEntry) {
        return pathPathItemEntry.getValue()
                .readOperationsMap()
                .entrySet()
                .stream()
                .map(methodOperationEntry -> {
                    EndpointDetails endpointDetails = buildEndpointDetails(pathPathItemEntry, methodOperationEntry);
                    return new SwaggerEndpoint(this, endpointDetails);
                })
                .toList()
                .stream();
    }

    private SwaggerEndpointDetails buildEndpointDetails(Map.Entry<String, PathItem> pathPathItemEntry,
                                                        Map.Entry<PathItem.HttpMethod, Operation> methodOperationEntry) {
        return SwaggerEndpointDetails.builder()
                .setMethod(methodOperationEntry.getKey())
                .setPath(pathPathItemEntry.getKey())
                .setParameters(methodOperationEntry.getValue().getParameters())
                .setRequestBody(methodOperationEntry.getValue().getRequestBody())
                .setTags(methodOperationEntry.getValue().getTags())
                .build();
    }

    @Override
    public DiscoverableApplication getDiscoverableApp() {
        return application;
    }

    @Override
    public String getName() {
        return application.getName();
    }

    @Override
    public List<SwaggerEndpoint> getEndpoints() {
        return List.copyOf(endpoints);
    }

    @Override
    public SwaggerParseResult getNativeDoc() {
        return doc;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object o) {
        if (this == o) return true;
        if (!(o instanceof SwaggerApplication that)) return false;

        return application.getName().equals(that.application.getName());
    }

    @Override
    public int hashCode() {
        return application.getName().hashCode();
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return MessageFormat.format("SwaggerApplication {0}", application.getName());
    }
}
```

```java
package com.example.dynamicgateway.model.documentedEndpoint;

import com.example.dynamicgateway.model.documentedApplication.DocumentedApplication;
import com.example.dynamicgateway.model.endpointDetails.EndpointDetails;

/**
 * Endpoint exposed by a {@link DocumentedApplication} as part of its public API
 *
 * @param <T> type of {@link DocumentedApplication} that exposes this endpoint
 */
public interface DocumentedEndpoint<T extends DocumentedApplication<?>> {
    T getDeclaringApp();

    EndpointDetails getDetails();
}
```

```java
package com.example.dynamicgateway.model.documentedEndpoint;

import com.example.dynamicgateway.model.documentedApplication.SwaggerApplication;
import com.example.dynamicgateway.model.endpointDetails.EndpointDetails;
import lombok.Getter;

import java.text.MessageFormat;
import java.util.Objects;
import java.util.stream.Stream;

/**
 * {@link DocumentedEndpoint} exposed by a {@link SwaggerApplication}
 */
public class SwaggerEndpoint implements DocumentedEndpoint<SwaggerApplication> {
    private final SwaggerApplication documentedApp;
    @Getter
    private final EndpointDetails details;

    public SwaggerEndpoint(SwaggerApplication documentedApp, EndpointDetails details) {
        Stream.of(documentedApp, details).forEach(Objects::requireNonNull);
        this.documentedApp = documentedApp;
        this.details = details;
    }

    @Override
    public SwaggerApplication getDeclaringApp() {
        return documentedApp;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return MessageFormat.format(
                "{0} {1} {2}",
                documentedApp.getName(),
                details.getMethod(),
                details.getPath()
        );
    }

    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object o) {
        if (this == o) return true;
        if (!(o instanceof SwaggerEndpoint otherEndpoint)) return false;

        return documentedApp.getName().equals(otherEndpoint.getDeclaringApp().getName()) &&
                details.getMethod().equals(otherEndpoint.getDetails().getMethod()) &&
                details.getPath().equals(otherEndpoint.getDetails().getPath());
    }

    @Override
    public int hashCode() {
        int result = documentedApp.getName().hashCode();
        result = 31 * result + details.getMethod().hashCode();
        result = 31 * result + details.getPath().hashCode();
        return result;
    }
}
```

```java
package com.example.dynamicgateway.model.endpointDetails;

import com.example.dynamicgateway.model.endpointParameter.EndpointParameter;
import com.example.dynamicgateway.model.endpointRequestBody.EndpointRequestBody;
import org.springframework.http.HttpMethod;

import java.util.List;

public interface EndpointDetails {
    String getPath();

    String getNonPrefixedPath();

    String getPrefix();

    HttpMethod getMethod();

    List<String> getTags();

    List<? extends EndpointParameter> getParameters();

    EndpointRequestBody getRequestBody();
}
```

```java
package com.example.dynamicgateway.model.endpointDetails;

import com.example.dynamicgateway.model.endpointParameter.SwaggerParameter;
import com.example.dynamicgateway.model.endpointRequestBody.SwaggerRequestBody;
import io.swagger.v3.oas.models.PathItem;
import io.swagger.v3.oas.models.parameters.Parameter;
import io.swagger.v3.oas.models.parameters.RequestBody;
import lombok.Getter;
import org.springframework.http.HttpMethod;

import java.util.Collection;
import java.util.Collections;
import java.util.List;

@Getter
public class SwaggerEndpointDetails implements EndpointDetails {
    private final String path;
    private final HttpMethod method;
    private final List<SwaggerParameter> parameters;
    private final SwaggerRequestBody requestBody;
    private final List<String> tags;

    SwaggerEndpointDetails(Builder builder) {
        this.path = builder.getPath();
        this.method = builder.getMethod();
        this.parameters = builder.getParameters();
        this.requestBody = builder.getRequestBody();
        this.tags = builder.getTags();
    }

    public static Builder builder() {
        return new Builder();
    }

    @Override
    public String getNonPrefixedPath() {
        return path.startsWith("/auth") ?
                path.substring(getPrefix().length()) :
                path;
    }

    @Override
    public String getPrefix() {
        return path.startsWith("/auth") ?
                "/auth" :
                "";
    }

    @Getter
    public static class Builder {
        private String path;
        private HttpMethod method;
        private List<SwaggerParameter> parameters;
        private SwaggerRequestBody requestBody;
        private List<String> tags;

        Builder() {
        }

        public Builder setPath(String path) {
            this.path = isNullOrBlank(path) ? "/" : path;
            return this;
        }

        private boolean isNullOrBlank(String path) {
            return path == null || path.isBlank();
        }

        public Builder setMethod(PathItem.HttpMethod method) {
            this.method = (method == null) ?
                    HttpMethod.GET :
                    HttpMethod.valueOf(method.toString());
            return this;
        }

        public Builder setParameters(List<Parameter> parameters) {
            this.parameters = isNullOrEmpty(parameters) ?
                    Collections.emptyList() :
                    parameters.stream().map(SwaggerParameter::new).toList();
            return this;
        }

        private boolean isNullOrEmpty(Collection<?> collection) {
            return collection == null || collection.isEmpty();
        }

        public Builder setRequestBody(RequestBody requestBody) {
            this.requestBody = (requestBody == null) ?
                    SwaggerRequestBody.empty() :
                    new SwaggerRequestBody(requestBody);
            return this;
        }

        public Builder setTags(List<String> tags) {
            this.tags = isNullOrEmpty(tags) ?
                    Collections.emptyList() :
                    tags;
            return this;
        }

        public SwaggerEndpointDetails build() {
            return new SwaggerEndpointDetails(this);
        }

        public String toString() {
            return "SwaggerEndpointDetails.Builder(path=" + this.path + ", method=" + this.method + ", parameters=" + this.parameters + ", requestBody=" + this.requestBody + ", tags=" + this.tags + ")";
        }
    }
}
```

```java
package com.example.dynamicgateway.model.endpointParameter;

public interface EndpointParameter {
    String getName();

    boolean isRequired();
}
```

```java
package com.example.dynamicgateway.model.endpointParameter;


import io.swagger.v3.oas.models.parameters.Parameter;
import lombok.RequiredArgsConstructor;

@RequiredArgsConstructor
public class SwaggerParameter implements EndpointParameter {
    private final Parameter parameter;

    @Override
    public String getName() {
        return parameter.getName();
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isRequired() {
        return parameter.getRequired();
    }
}
```

```java
// this part is rudimentary

package com.example.dynamicgateway.model.endpointRequestBody;

public interface EndpointRequestBody {
    boolean isRequired();
}
```

```java
package com.example.dynamicgateway.model.endpointRequestBody;

import io.swagger.v3.oas.models.parameters.RequestBody;
import lombok.RequiredArgsConstructor;

@RequiredArgsConstructor
public class SwaggerRequestBody implements EndpointRequestBody {
    private final RequestBody requestBody;

    public static SwaggerRequestBody empty() {
        return new SwaggerRequestBody(new RequestBody());
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isRequired() {
        return (requestBody.getRequired() != null) &&
                requestBody.getRequired();
    }
}
```

```java
package com.example.dynamicgateway.model.gatewayMeta;

import io.swagger.v3.oas.models.servers.Server;
import lombok.Setter;
import org.springframework.boot.context.properties.ConfigurationProperties;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Component;

import java.util.List;

/**
 * Holder of meta information relating to this Gateway
 */
@Component
@ConfigurationProperties(prefix = "gateway")
@Setter
public final class GatewayMeta {
    private List<Server> servers;
    private String v1Prefix;
    private String[] publicPatterns;
    private String[] ignoredPatterns;

    public List<Server> servers() {
        return this.servers;
    }

    public String v1Prefix() {
        return this.v1Prefix;
    }

    public String[] publicPatterns() {
        return this.publicPatterns;
    }

    public String[] ignoredPatterns() {
        return this.ignoredPatterns;
    }
}
```

```java
package com.example.dynamicgateway.model.uiConfig;

import com.example.dynamicgateway.model.documentedApplication.SwaggerApplication;
import com.example.dynamicgateway.service.swaggerUiSupport.SwaggerUiConfigSerializer;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonProperty;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.annotation.JsonSerialize;
import lombok.Getter;
import lombok.NoArgsConstructor;

import java.util.Collection;

@NoArgsConstructor
@Getter
public class SwaggerUiConfig {
    @JsonProperty("urls")
    @JsonSerialize(contentUsing = SwaggerUiConfigSerializer.class)
    private Collection<SwaggerApplication> swaggerApplications;

    public SwaggerUiConfig(Collection<SwaggerApplication> swaggerApplications) {
        this.swaggerApplications = swaggerApplications;
    }

    public static SwaggerUiConfig from(Collection<SwaggerApplication> swaggerApplications) {
        return new SwaggerUiConfig(swaggerApplications);
    }
}
```

## Event

```java
package com.example.dynamicgateway.events;

import com.example.dynamicgateway.model.documentedEndpoint.DocumentedEndpoint;
import lombok.Getter;
import org.springframework.context.ApplicationEvent;

/**
 * Event published to indicate a discovery of a new {@link DocumentedEndpoint}
 */
@Getter
public class DocumentedEndpointFoundEvent extends ApplicationEvent {
    private final DocumentedEndpoint<?> foundEndpoint;

    public DocumentedEndpointFoundEvent(DocumentedEndpoint<?> foundEndpoint, Object source) {
        super(source);
        this.foundEndpoint = foundEndpoint;
    }
}
```

## Controller

```java
// rudimentary

package com.example.dynamicgateway.controller;

import lombok.Getter;
import lombok.NoArgsConstructor;
import lombok.extern.slf4j.Slf4j;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.GetMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RestController;
import reactor.core.publisher.Mono;

@RestController
@Slf4j
public class FallbackController {
    @GetMapping("/fallback")
    public Mono<CircuitBreakerFallbackMessage> getFallback() {
        return Mono.just(new CircuitBreakerFallbackMessage());
    }

    @NoArgsConstructor
    @Getter
    public static class CircuitBreakerFallbackMessage {
        private final String message = "Service unavailable";
    }
}
```

```java
package com.example.dynamicgateway.controller;

import com.example.dynamicgateway.service.swaggerUiSupport.SwaggerUiSupport;
import io.swagger.v3.oas.models.OpenAPI;
import lombok.RequiredArgsConstructor;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.GetMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.PathVariable;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RestController;
import reactor.core.publisher.Mono;

@RestController
@RequiredArgsConstructor
public class SwaggerDocController {
    private final SwaggerUiSupport uiSupport;

    @GetMapping("/doc/{application-name}")
    public Mono<OpenAPI> getSwaggerAppDoc(@PathVariable("application-name") String applicationName) {
        return uiSupport.getSwaggerAppDoc(applicationName);
    }
}
```

```java
package com.example.dynamicgateway.controller;

import com.example.dynamicgateway.model.uiConfig.SwaggerUiConfig;
import com.example.dynamicgateway.service.swaggerUiSupport.SwaggerUiSupport;
import lombok.RequiredArgsConstructor;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.GetMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RestController;
import reactor.core.publisher.Mono;

@RestController
@RequiredArgsConstructor
public class SwaggerUiConfigController {
    private final SwaggerUiSupport uiSupport;

    @GetMapping("/swagger-ui/config")
    public Mono<SwaggerUiConfig> getConfig() {
        return uiSupport.getSwaggerUiConfig();
    }
}
```

## Constant

```java
package com.example.dynamicgateway.constant;

public class JWT {
    public static final String HEADER = "Authorization";
    public static final String KEY = "jxgEQeXHuPq8VdbyYFNkANdudQ53YUn4";
    public static final String SUB = "sub";
    public static final String ROLES = "roles";

    private JWT() {
    }
}
```

## Config

```java
package com.example.dynamicgateway.config.security;

import com.example.dynamicgateway.config.security.filter.JwtAuthorizationFilter;
import com.example.dynamicgateway.model.gatewayMeta.GatewayMeta;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.http.HttpStatus;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.reactive.EnableWebFluxSecurity;
import org.springframework.security.config.web.server.SecurityWebFiltersOrder;
import org.springframework.security.config.web.server.ServerHttpSecurity;
import org.springframework.security.web.server.SecurityWebFilterChain;
import org.springframework.security.web.server.context.NoOpServerSecurityContextRepository;
import org.springframework.web.cors.CorsConfiguration;
import org.springframework.web.cors.reactive.CorsConfigurationSource;
import org.springframework.web.cors.reactive.UrlBasedCorsConfigurationSource;
import org.springframework.web.server.WebFilter;
import reactor.core.publisher.Mono;

import java.time.Duration;
import java.util.Collections;
import java.util.List;

@Configuration
@EnableWebFluxSecurity
public class SecurityConfig {
    private final GatewayMeta gatewayMeta;

    public SecurityConfig(GatewayMeta gatewayMeta) {
        this.gatewayMeta = gatewayMeta;
    }
    @Bean
    public SecurityWebFilterChain filterChain(ServerHttpSecurity http) {
        return http
                .csrf(ServerHttpSecurity.CsrfSpec::disable)
                .securityContextRepository(NoOpServerSecurityContextRepository.getInstance())
                .httpBasic(ServerHttpSecurity.HttpBasicSpec::disable)
                .formLogin(ServerHttpSecurity.FormLoginSpec::disable)
                .authorizeExchange(exchanges -> exchanges
                        .pathMatchers(gatewayMeta.publicPatterns()).permitAll()
                        .anyExchange().authenticated()
                )
                .addFilterBefore(jwtAuthorizationFilter(), SecurityWebFiltersOrder.AUTHORIZATION)
                .exceptionHandling(exceptionHandlingSpec -> exceptionHandlingSpec
                        .authenticationEntryPoint((exchange, ex) -> Mono.fromRunnable(
                                () -> exchange.getResponse().setStatusCode(HttpStatus.UNAUTHORIZED)
                        )))
                .cors(corsSpec -> corsSpec.configurationSource(corsConfiguration()))
                .build();
    }

    private CorsConfigurationSource corsConfiguration() {
        UrlBasedCorsConfigurationSource source = new UrlBasedCorsConfigurationSource();
        CorsConfiguration config = new CorsConfiguration();
        config.setAllowedMethods(Collections.singletonList("*"));
        config.setAllowCredentials(true);
        config.setAllowedHeaders(Collections.singletonList("*"));
        config.setExposedHeaders(List.of("Authorization"));
        config.setMaxAge(Duration.ofHours(1));
        config.setAllowedOriginPatterns(List.of("*"));
        source.registerCorsConfiguration("/**", config);
        return source;
    }

    @Bean
    public WebFilter jwtAuthorizationFilter() {
        return new JwtAuthorizationFilter();
    }
}
```

```java
package com.example.dynamicgateway.config.security.filter;

import com.example.dynamicgateway.constant.JWT;
import io.jsonwebtoken.Claims;
import io.jsonwebtoken.ExpiredJwtException;
import io.jsonwebtoken.Jwts;
import io.jsonwebtoken.MalformedJwtException;
import io.jsonwebtoken.security.Keys;
import io.jsonwebtoken.security.SignatureException;
import lombok.extern.slf4j.Slf4j;
import org.springframework.core.io.buffer.DataBuffer;
import org.springframework.core.io.buffer.DefaultDataBufferFactory;
import org.springframework.http.HttpStatus;
import org.springframework.http.server.reactive.ServerHttpResponse;
import org.springframework.security.authentication.UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken;
import org.springframework.security.core.GrantedAuthority;
import org.springframework.security.core.authority.SimpleGrantedAuthority;
import org.springframework.security.core.context.ReactiveSecurityContextHolder;
import org.springframework.web.server.ServerWebExchange;
import org.springframework.web.server.WebFilter;
import org.springframework.web.server.WebFilterChain;
import reactor.core.publisher.Mono;

import javax.crypto.SecretKey;
import java.nio.charset.StandardCharsets;
import java.util.Collections;
import java.util.List;

/**
 * WebFilter that extracts a JWT token from the request header and verifies its signature using a secret key.
 * If the token is valid, it sets the authentication object in the SecurityContextHolder.
 */
@Slf4j
public class JwtAuthorizationFilter implements WebFilter {

    /**
     * Filters the incoming request and sets the authentication object in the SecurityContextHolder if the JWT token is valid.
     *
     * @param exchange the ServerWebExchange object representing the incoming request and outgoing response
     * @param chain    the WebFilterChain object representing the filter chain to be executed
     * @return a Mono<Void> representing the completion of the filter chain
     */
    @Override
    public Mono<Void> filter(ServerWebExchange exchange, WebFilterChain chain) {
        String jwt = exchange.getRequest().getHeaders().getFirst(JWT.HEADER);

        if (jwt != null) {
            try {
                return authenticateAndFilter(exchange, chain, jwt);
            } catch (ExpiredJwtException e) {
                log.error("Token has expired. " + e.getMessage());
                return createError(exchange, e);
            } catch (SignatureException e) {
                log.error("Token signature cannot be verified. " + e.getMessage());
                return createError(exchange, e);
            } catch (MalformedJwtException e) {
                log.error("Token is not properly formatted. " + e.getMessage());
                return createError(exchange, e);
            } catch (Exception e) {
                log.error("Error parsing token. " + e.getMessage());
                return createError(exchange, e);
            }
        }
        return chain.filter(exchange);
    }

    private Mono<Void> authenticateAndFilter(ServerWebExchange exchange, WebFilterChain chain, String jwt) {
        UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken upat = buildUpat(jwt);
        return chain.filter(exchange).contextWrite(ReactiveSecurityContextHolder.withAuthentication(upat));
    }

    private UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken buildUpat(String jwt) {
        Claims claims = getClaims(jwt);

        Object clientId = getPrincipalName(claims);
        List<? extends GrantedAuthority> authorities = getGrantedAuthorities(claims);

        return new UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken(clientId, null, authorities);
    }

    private Claims getClaims(String jwt) {
        SecretKey hashedKey = Keys.hmacShaKeyFor(JWT.KEY.getBytes(StandardCharsets.UTF_8));

        return Jwts.parserBuilder()
                .setSigningKey(hashedKey)
                .build()
                .parseClaimsJws(jwt)
                .getBody();
    }

    private Object getPrincipalName(Claims claims) {
        return claims.get(JWT.SUB);
    }

    private List<? extends GrantedAuthority> getGrantedAuthorities(Claims claims) {
        Object nullableRoles = claims.get(JWT.ROLES);
        return (nullableRoles instanceof List<?> roles) ?
                buildGrantedAuthoritiesFrom(roles) :
                Collections.emptyList();
    }

    private List<SimpleGrantedAuthority> buildGrantedAuthoritiesFrom(List<?> roles) {
        return roles.stream()
                .map(Object::toString)
                .map(SimpleGrantedAuthority::new)
                .toList();
    }

    private Mono<Void> createError(ServerWebExchange exchange, Exception e) {
        ServerHttpResponse response = exchange.getResponse();
        response.setStatusCode(HttpStatus.UNAUTHORIZED);
        return response.writeWith(Mono.just(createErrorBody(e.getMessage())));
    }

    private DataBuffer createErrorBody(String errorBody) {
        byte[] bytes = errorBody.getBytes();
        return new DefaultDataBufferFactory().wrap(bytes);
    }
}
```

```java
package com.example.dynamicgateway.config;

import com.example.dynamicgateway.model.gatewayMeta.GatewayMeta;
import com.example.dynamicgateway.service.endpointSieve.EndpointSieve;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.util.AntPathMatcher;

import java.util.Arrays;

@Configuration
public class EndpointSieveConfig {
    @Bean
    public EndpointSieve errorPathEndpointSieve(GatewayMeta gatewayMeta, AntPathMatcher antPathMatcher) {
        return endpoint -> Arrays.stream(gatewayMeta.ignoredPatterns())
                .noneMatch(ignoredPattern -> antPathMatcher.match(ignoredPattern, endpoint.getDetails().getPath()));
    }

    @Bean
    public AntPathMatcher antPathMatcher() {
        return new AntPathMatcher();
    }
}
```

```java
package com.example.dynamicgateway.config;

import com.example.dynamicgateway.client.ApplicationDocClient;
import com.example.dynamicgateway.client.SwaggerClientConfigurer;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonInclude;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper;
import io.swagger.v3.parser.core.models.SwaggerParseResult;
import org.springframework.cloud.client.loadbalancer.LoadBalanced;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.web.reactive.function.client.WebClient;

@Configuration
public class ClientConfig {
    @Bean
    @LoadBalanced
    public WebClient.Builder balancedWebClientBuilder() {
        return WebClient.builder();
    }

    @Bean
    public ApplicationDocClient<SwaggerParseResult> applicationDocClient() {
        return SwaggerClientConfigurer.configure(balancedWebClientBuilder().build()).build();
    }

    @Bean
    public ObjectMapper objectMapper() {
        ObjectMapper objectMapper = new ObjectMapper();
        objectMapper.setSerializationInclusion(JsonInclude.Include.NON_NULL);
        return objectMapper;
    }
}
```

```java
package com.example.dynamicgateway.config;

import io.github.resilience4j.circuitbreaker.CircuitBreakerConfig;
import io.github.resilience4j.timelimiter.TimeLimiterConfig;
import org.springframework.cloud.circuitbreaker.resilience4j.ReactiveResilience4JCircuitBreakerFactory;
import org.springframework.cloud.circuitbreaker.resilience4j.Resilience4JConfigBuilder;
import org.springframework.cloud.client.circuitbreaker.Customizer;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;

import java.time.Duration;

@Configuration
public class MyCircuitBreakerConfig {
    @Bean
    public Customizer<ReactiveResilience4JCircuitBreakerFactory> circuitBreakerCustomizer() {
        return factory -> factory.configureDefault(id -> new Resilience4JConfigBuilder(id)
                .circuitBreakerConfig(CircuitBreakerConfig.ofDefaults())
                .timeLimiterConfig(TimeLimiterConfig.custom()
                        .timeoutDuration(Duration.ofSeconds(5))
                        .build())
                .build());
    }
}
```

```java
package com.example.dynamicgateway.config;

import com.example.dynamicgateway.model.discoverableApplication.DiscoverableApplication;
import com.example.dynamicgateway.model.documentedEndpoint.DocumentedEndpoint;
import com.example.dynamicgateway.model.endpointParameter.EndpointParameter;
import com.example.dynamicgateway.model.gatewayMeta.GatewayMeta;
import com.example.dynamicgateway.service.paramInitializer.ParamInitializer;
import com.example.dynamicgateway.service.paramInitializer.ParamInitializers;
import com.example.dynamicgateway.service.routeProcessor.EndpointRouteProcessor;
import lombok.RequiredArgsConstructor;
import org.springframework.cloud.gateway.filter.OrderedGatewayFilter;
import org.springframework.cloud.gateway.filter.factory.PrefixPathGatewayFilterFactory;
import org.springframework.cloud.gateway.filter.factory.RewritePathGatewayFilterFactory;
import org.springframework.cloud.gateway.filter.factory.SpringCloudCircuitBreakerFilterFactory;
import org.springframework.cloud.gateway.handler.predicate.MethodRoutePredicateFactory;
import org.springframework.cloud.gateway.handler.predicate.PathRoutePredicateFactory;
import org.springframework.cloud.gateway.route.Route;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.core.annotation.Order;

import java.util.List;
import java.util.Optional;
import java.util.UUID;

@Configuration
@RequiredArgsConstructor
public class RouteProcessorConfig {
    private final GatewayMeta gatewayMeta;

    @Bean
    @Order(0)
    public EndpointRouteProcessor basePredicateProcessor() {
        return (routeInConstruction, endpoint) -> {
            setBasePredicate(routeInConstruction, endpoint);
            return routeInConstruction;
        };
    }

    /**
     * Sets base route predicate matching Gateway's prefix plus endpoint path stripped of non-semantic prefixes. For example,
     * if the passed endpoint's path is {@code /auth/example}, {@code /auth} is the endpoint's non-semantic prefix, and
     * Gateway's prefix is {@code /api/v1}, this method will set a base predicate matching {@code /api/v1/example}
     */
    private void setBasePredicate(Route.AsyncBuilder routeInConstruction, DocumentedEndpoint<?> endpoint) {
        routeInConstruction.asyncPredicate(
                new PathRoutePredicateFactory()
                        .applyAsync(c -> c.setPatterns(List.of(gatewayMeta.v1Prefix() + endpoint.getDetails().getNonPrefixedPath())))
        );
    }

    @Bean
    @Order(1)
    public EndpointRouteProcessor removeGatewayPrefixRouteProcessor() {
        return (routeInConstruction, endpoint) -> {
            routeInConstruction.filter(
                    new OrderedGatewayFilter(
                            new RewritePathGatewayFilterFactory().apply(config -> config
                                    .setRegexp(gatewayMeta.v1Prefix())
                                    .setReplacement("")), 0)
            );
            return routeInConstruction;
        };
    }

    @Bean
    @Order(2)
    public EndpointRouteProcessor uriRouteProcessor() {
        return (routeInConstruction, endpoint) -> {
            DiscoverableApplication discoverableApp = endpoint.getDeclaringApp().getDiscoverableApp();
            return routeInConstruction.uri(discoverableApp.getDiscoveryServiceScheme() + discoverableApp.getName());
        };
    }

    @Bean
    @Order(3)
    public EndpointRouteProcessor appendEndpointPrefixRouteProcessor() {
        return (routeInConstruction, endpoint) -> {
            String endpointPrefix = endpoint.getDetails().getPrefix();
            if (!endpointPrefix.isEmpty()) {
                routeInConstruction.filter(
                        new OrderedGatewayFilter(
                                new PrefixPathGatewayFilterFactory().apply(config -> config
                                        .setPrefix(endpointPrefix)), 0)
                );
            }
            return routeInConstruction;
        };
    }

    @Bean
    @Order(4)
    public EndpointRouteProcessor idRouteProcessor() {
        return (routeInConstruction, endpoint) -> routeInConstruction.id(UUID.randomUUID().toString());
    }

    @Bean
    public EndpointRouteProcessor methodRouteProcessor() {
        return (routeInConstruction, endpoint) -> {
            appendHttpMethodPredicate(routeInConstruction, endpoint);
            return routeInConstruction;
        };
    }

    private void appendHttpMethodPredicate(Route.AsyncBuilder routeInConstruction, DocumentedEndpoint<?> endpoint) {
        routeInConstruction.and(
                new MethodRoutePredicateFactory().applyAsync(c ->
                        c.setMethods(endpoint.getDetails().getMethod()))
        );
    }

    @Bean
    public EndpointRouteProcessor paramInitializingRouteProcessor(ParamInitializers paramInitializers) {
        return (routeInConstruction, endpoint) -> {
            for (EndpointParameter param : endpoint.getDetails().getParameters()) {
                Optional<ParamInitializer> optionalParamInitializer = paramInitializers.findInitializerForParam(param);
                optionalParamInitializer.ifPresent(
                        paramInitializer -> paramInitializer.initialize(routeInConstruction)
                );
            }
            return routeInConstruction;
        };
    }

    @Bean
    public EndpointRouteProcessor circuitBreakerEndpointRouteProcessor(SpringCloudCircuitBreakerFilterFactory filterFactory) {
        return (routeInConstruction, endpoint) -> {
            routeInConstruction.filter(filterFactory.apply(routeInConstruction.getId(), config -> config.setFallbackUri("/fallback")));
            return routeInConstruction;
        };
    }
}
```

## Client

```java
package com.example.dynamicgateway.client;

import com.example.dynamicgateway.model.discoverableApplication.DiscoverableApplication;
import reactor.core.publisher.Mono;

/**
 * Client that can be used to find exposed API documentation of a {@link DiscoverableApplication}
 *
 * @param <T> type of documentation object supplied by an application
 */
public interface ApplicationDocClient<T> {
    /**
     * Returns a {@code Mono} of documentation object
     * @param application queried application
     */
    Mono<T> findApplicationDoc(DiscoverableApplication application);
}
```

```java
package com.example.dynamicgateway.client;

import com.example.dynamicgateway.model.discoverableApplication.DiscoverableApplication;
import io.swagger.v3.parser.OpenAPIV3Parser;
import io.swagger.v3.parser.core.models.SwaggerParseResult;
import lombok.Getter;
import org.springframework.web.reactive.function.client.WebClient;
import reactor.core.publisher.Mono;

/**
 * An {@link ApplicationDocClient} implementation for finding Swagger (Open API) documentation exposed by {@link DiscoverableApplication}s
 */
@Getter
public class SwaggerClient implements ApplicationDocClient<SwaggerParseResult> {
    private final String scheme;
    private final String docPath;
    private final WebClient webClient;
    private final OpenAPIV3Parser parser;

    SwaggerClient(SwaggerClientConfigurer configurer) {
        this.scheme = configurer.getScheme();
        this.docPath = configurer.getDocPath();
        this.webClient = configurer.getWebClient();
        parser = new OpenAPIV3Parser();
    }

    @Override
    public Mono<SwaggerParseResult> findApplicationDoc(DiscoverableApplication application) {
        return webClient
                .get()
                .uri(scheme + application.getName() + docPath)
                .retrieve()
                .bodyToMono(String.class)
                .map(parser::readContents);
    }
}
```

```java
package com.example.dynamicgateway.client;

import com.example.dynamicgateway.model.discoverableApplication.DiscoverableApplication;
import com.example.dynamicgateway.model.discoverableApplication.EurekaDiscoverableApplication;
import com.example.dynamicgateway.model.documentedApplication.SwaggerApplication;
import lombok.Getter;
import org.springframework.web.reactive.function.client.WebClient;

import java.util.regex.Pattern;

/**
 * Class for configuring and creating {@link SwaggerClient} instances
 */
public class SwaggerClientConfigurer {
    @Getter
    private String scheme = EurekaDiscoverableApplication.LB_SCHEME;
    @Getter
    private String docPath = SwaggerApplication.V3_DOC_PATH;
    private final WebClient resolvingWebClient;

    private SwaggerClientConfigurer(WebClient resolvingWebClient) {
        this.resolvingWebClient = resolvingWebClient;
    }

    /**
     * Factory method returning a {@code SwaggerClientConfigurer} instance
     *
     * @param resolvingWebClient {@code WebClient} that is capable of resolving {@link DiscoverableApplication}
     *                           names into specific servers
     * @return {@code SwaggerClientConfigurer} with default field values
     */
    public static SwaggerClientConfigurer configure(WebClient resolvingWebClient) {
        return new SwaggerClientConfigurer(resolvingWebClient);
    }

    /**
     * Sets this scheme unless the passed string does not represent a valid scheme
     * (one or more lower-case Latin letters followed by a colon and two forward slashes).
     * If the method is not invoked, the scheme defaults to {@link EurekaDiscoverableApplication#LB_SCHEME}
     *
     * @return this {@code SwaggerClientConfigurer}
     * @throws IllegalArgumentException if the passed scheme string is invalid
     */
    public SwaggerClientConfigurer setScheme(String scheme) {
        checkScheme(scheme);
        this.scheme = scheme;
        return this;
    }

    private void checkScheme(String scheme) {
        boolean matchesSchemePattern = Pattern.matches("[a-z]+://", scheme);
        if (!matchesSchemePattern) {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("Invalid scheme: " + scheme);
        }
    }

    /**
     * Sets this documentation path.
     * If the method is not invoked, the path defaults to {@link SwaggerApplication#V3_DOC_PATH}
     *
     * @return this {@code SwaggerClientConfigurer}
     */
    public SwaggerClientConfigurer setDocPath(String docPath) {
        this.docPath = docPath;
        return this;
    }

    /**
     * Returns a {@code SwaggerClient} instance constructed from this {@code SwaggerClientConfigurer}
     */
    public SwaggerClient build() {
        return new SwaggerClient(this);
    }

    public WebClient getWebClient() {
        return resolvingWebClient;
    }
}
```

Comment: **What I'm not happy about:**

Comment: 1. No route eviction. Once it's built, there's no way out for it, even if the service is down. Removing relevant endpoints on "Service deregistered" events would be nice to have

Comment: 2. Similarly, I want my `EndpointCollector` to poll Kafka events "Service added" published by Eureka server and fetch docs only from those new services instead of fetching likely the same docs from all services every 30 seconds, but I don't have practical knowledge of Kafka

Comment: 3. If a Eureka service doesn't expose it's API as this Gateway expects, the console is defaced by a a 404 error. I want to catch that kind of exceptions and simply `log.warn` something. However, I couldn't catch anything in this reactive environment (I tried `onErrorContinue()`)

Comment: 4. I can't get the `Authorize` button to work in my Swagger UI. I'm not sure whether it has to do with the Gateway or the service. See [this StackOverflow page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77717946/enabling-an-authorize-button-in-swagger-ui-declaratively) for more details